# Edit components in Apache bloodhound

Tags: trac, apache-bloodhound

I have installed Apache BloodHound 0.7. And I believe it internally uses Trac 1.0. Therefore, as this [link](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/WebAdmin) suggests WebAdmin is already included in this version.

But still I am not able to open the components page. `http://localhost:8000/main/admin/ticket/components`
[image: Page not found error]

Also, I dont see the components in the admin console as it should be:
[image: Components not found under the Tickets System]

Kindly let me know how to get them so that I can edit the components.

Comment: The Components are product-scope. The admin page can be accessed by changing the drop-down __(Global settings)__ shown in your screen capture.

Answer (score 1):

In command-prompt, Syntax to add a component to a product:

```
(bhenv)bash-4.1$ trac-admin <environment-path> product admin <product-prefix> component add <component-name> <owner><br>
```

For example, to add a component named **login** in bloodhound default product, **@** with ownership **bloodhound**:

```
(bhenv)bash-4.1$ trac-admin /home/bloodhound/apache-bloodhound-0.8/installer/bloodhound/environments/main product admin @ component add login bloodhound
```

(or)
**Caution : Editing in database may introduce anomalies!**
It can be edited in the database. If postgres is used with bloodhound:

```
psql --host=localhost --port=5432 --username=bloodhound --password
password:xxxx
```

**Delete the default components in your product created by bloodhound:**

```
delete from public.component where product = '<product-prefix>';
```

**To delete the default components in default product ie.@:**

```
delete from public.component where product = '@';
```

**Check whether any default component is there by querying:**

```
select * from public.component;
```

**Create the required components in your product:**

```
insert into public.component (name, owner, description, product) values ('<Component Name>', '<Owner>', '<Component Description>', '<Product-Prefix>');
```

**To create the required components in default product, @:**

```
insert into public.component (name, owner, description, product) values ('Login Page', 'bloodhound', 'For User Authentication', '@');
```

Similarly, it can be done in MySQL or SQLite also!

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped me remove a misplaced ticket: Trac [/apache-bloodhound-0.8/installer/bloodhound/environments/main]> product admin @ ticket remove 2